compute a scale factor for use in includegraphics
I want to compute a scale factor for use in includegraphics.  I want to do this using the declarations from xparse.  What I have so far (based mostly on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437494/293199):
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\dimratio { m m }
{
 \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
 \fp_eval:n
  {
   \dim_to_fp:n { #2 } /  \dim_to_fp:n { \wd0 }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\myscalex{\dimratio{example-image.png}{0.75\textwidth}}

\myscalex

\includegraphics[width=0.75\textwidth]{example-image.png}

\includegraphics[scale=\myscalex]{example-image.png}

\end{document}

But I get the following error:
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.23 ...aphics[scale=\myscalex]{example-image.png}
                                                  
? H
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

I think the problem is that \myscalex is the wrong type of thing.  I don't think it's a length, but I don't what it is.  It would also be great if you could give a summary of why \includegraphics[scale=\myscalex]{...} isn't acceptable.
If I could get my example to work, it would show example-image.png at 75% of \textwidth, followed by "0.72851..." and then another example-image.png at 75% of \textwidth.
I'd love it if I could define dimratio such that I could use something like
\includegraphics[scale=\dimratio{example-image.png}{0.75\textwidth}]{example-image.png}

but I understand that may not be possible.
I did try looking up 'weird error' in The TeXBook https://archive.org/details/B-001-002-139 but all I found was an exercise for the reader :(  -- https://archive.org/details/B-001-002-139/page/n307/mode/2up?q=weird
I'm aware of the following answers

Multiplying width by a scaling factor in \includegraphics is similar but produces a length, not for "scale=..."
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437494/293199 generates a scale factor but only uses it to multiply a length, never as "scale=..."
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443400/293199 this would be spot on: using xparse and generating output for "scale=...", but I don't see what I'm doing so differently

[EDIT]
I'm trying to scale and then trim my image (yes, like How to scale and then trim an image?) but I was trying something different and the problem I've run into seemed liked its own question.

The main issue here is that you have an assignment (\sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}) within \dimratio, which isn't expandable. Any reason why you want to scale things dynamically and not just set the width? Alternatively, you may define a new macro \includescaledgraphics, say, that manages your scaling.

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand does not make non expandable things such as box assignments expandable. Also you don't need xparse unless you have an old latex. define dimratio  tohave a third argumnet that saves the result then use that in includegraphics so  \dimratio{example-image.png}{0.75\textwidth}\myscale  then \includegraphics[scale=\myscale]

@Werner, I think that means I need to find a function that would return the width of \includegraphics{#1}.  if you could suggest such a function or let me know where to find it, that would be really great

@DavidCarlisle, I followed your suggestion about adding a third argument for saving the result.  I was able to compile my example and get the result I've been looking for.  Thank you!

@troy This sounds as if it might be an xy-problem. Can you add some background information why you want to scale the image?

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand does not make non expandable things such as box assignments expandable. Also you don't need xparse unless you have an old latex.
Define \dimratio to have a third argumnet that saves the result then use that in includegraphics so
\dimratio{example-image.png}{0.75\textwidth}\myscale

then
\includegraphics[scale=\myscale]


based on the answer from @DavidCarlisle , this seems to work pretty well
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\mydimratiobox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\dimratio { m m m }
{
  \sbox\mydimratiobox{\includegraphics{#1}}
  \newcommand{#3}{\fp_eval:n
    {
     round (  \dim_to_fp:n { #2 } /  \dim_to_fp:n { \wd\mydimratiobox } , 5)
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\dimratio{example-image.png}{0.3\textwidth}{\scalea}

\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=\scalea, trim = 0mm 0mm 3.5cm 0mm, clip=true]{example-image.png}}

\end{document}


You should remove Expandable and also use \sbox\mydimratiobox= instead of \setbox\mydimratiobox=\hbox. Also \newsavebox is preferable to \newbox.

I still cannot find a reason to set a scale factor for one picture based on a different one.

@egreg, I'm computing a scale factor based on the image size before trimming.  \includegraphics[width=..., trim=..., clip=true] applies the trim and then scales to the width.  I wanted to scale first and then trim.  I know that this was addressed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60918/how-to-scale-and-then-trim-an-image.  I posed the question as I did because I'm trying to learn how to use \NewDocumentCommand, etc.    Thank you for your suggestions and edits.
